# Magento 2 API - Update Product Custom Attribute to Blank/Null

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, custom-attributes

I am trying to update a product via the Magento 2 Rest API.

If an attribute already has a value I can update that value with another value with no problems.

However if I want to delete the value and leave the attribute blank it will not update and just leaves the old value in place.

I have tried submitting NULL and blank values but with no effect.

```
array( 'attribute_code' => 'standard_consumables', 'value' => '' ),
array( 'attribute_code' => 'standard_consumables', 'value' => NULL ),
```

How can I remove a custom attribute value via the REST API.

Thanks

Comment: do you found answer for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Niether did I :( I've been finding too many Magento REST API  questions unanswered :/

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in 2.2.x, see:

- [REST API: Cannot delete custom attribute from product #10807](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10807) for issue thread, and
- [Support null value for custom attributes.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9e3ca7b3cb297741696bb4c25e0c8ad28ea7d87f) for the fix